# Infimum of complex expression on the unit disc in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Suppose $|\lambda|<1, Re\lambda < 0, Im\lambda > 0$. What is the largest lower bound independent of $\lambda$ on the expression

$$\frac{1+|\lambda|^2}{2}+Re\lambda - \frac{2\pi}{n+2}Im\lambda$$ where $n$ is a positive integer? If you like, stipulate that $n$ be as large as you need for the problem to make sense, though make it as small of a lower bound on $n$ as you can, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is equivalent to the bivariate real optimization problem:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & \frac{1+x^2+y^2}{2}+x-\frac{2\pi}{n+2} y \\
\text{subject to} & x^2 + y^2 \leq 1
\end{array}
To solve, we build the Lagrangian
$$L(x,y,z) = \frac{1+x^2+y^2}{2}+x-\frac{2\pi}{n+2} y - z(1 - x^2 - y^2)$$
where $z \geq 0$ is the Lagrange multiplier. The optimality conditions are
$$x + 1 + 2zx = 0 \quad y - \frac{2\pi}{n+2} + 2zy = 0 \quad x^2+y^2\leq 1$$
Rearranging,
$$x = \frac{-1}{1+2z} \quad y = \frac{2\pi}{(1+2z)(n+2)}$$
Note that if we were to guess that $z=0$---its smallest legal value---then we'd see that $x=1$ and $x^2+y^2>1$. Therefore it *must* be the case that $z>0$, and complementary slackness tells us this implies $x^2+y^2=1$. So we solve:
$$x^2 + y^2 = \frac{1}{(1+2z)^2} \left( 1 + \frac{4\pi^2}{(n+2)^2}\right) = 1$$
which leads us to
$$\frac{1}{1+2z} = (1+(4\pi^2)/(n+2)^2)^{-1/2}$$
Substitution yields
$$x = \frac{-1}{(1+(4\pi^2)/(n+2)^2)^{1/2}}, \quad y = \frac{2\pi}{(n+2)(1+(4\pi^2)/(n+2)^2)^{1/2}}$$
Then bring this back into the expression: Since $x^2+y^2=1$, that first term is equal to 1, and we have
$$1 - \frac{1+(4\pi^2)/(n+2)^2}{(1+(4\pi^2)/(n+2)^2)^{1/2}} = 1 - (1+(4\pi^2)/(n+2)^2)^{1/2}$$

Comment: Sorry for all the edits. Please scrub my math, people. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Let us give values to the real and imaginary parts of $\lambda $ to make that expression as small as possible while following your constraints.

The expression is

$$\frac{1+|\lambda|^2}{2}+Re\lambda - \frac{2\pi}{n+2}Im\lambda$$

And we want to minimize all the terms.

$\frac{1+|\lambda|^2}{2}$ is as small as $|\lambda|$ is so make it 0, which is as small as it can get.

$Re\lambda$ cannot go below $-1$ otherwise $|\lambda| > 1$ so make it $-1$.

$ -\frac{2\pi}{n+2}Im\lambda$ gets smaller when $Im\lambda$ gets bigger so let us say $Im\lambda = 1$ since it can't go any bigger: $|\lambda| < 1$. Then the expression becomes

$$\frac{1+|\lambda|^2}{2}+Re\lambda - \frac{2\pi}{n+2}Im\lambda = \frac{1}{2} - 1 - \frac{2\pi}{n+2} = -(\frac{2\pi}{n+2} + \frac {1}{2})$$ which is the best bound I can think of.

Comment: I asked for the largest lower bound ;)

Comment: @JohnnyApple ok, and there it is. I am surely not saying that this one is the best bound you can think of, but it surely is the best bound you can get withouth going into the realms of weird calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a lower bound by solving:
$$
\begin{align}
\min_{a,b} \quad & \frac{1 + a^2 + b^2}{2} + a - \frac{2\pi}{n+2}b \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & a^2 + b^2 \leq 1 \\
& a \leq 0 \\
& b \geq 0 \\
\end{align}
$$
Note that by taking the closure if the feasible set, I can write $\min$ instead of $\inf$. This problem can be solved for fixed $n$ by any convex optimization solver. I used ipopt. Here is a set of optimal values:
$$
\begin{align}
n & & \textrm{value} \\
1 & & -1.32 \\
2 & & -0.862 \\
3 & & -0.606\\
4 & & -0.448 \\
5 & & -0.344 \\
10 & & -0.129 \\
100 & & -0.00160 \\
1002 & & -0.0000197 \\
\end{align}
$$
In the optimum for $n=1$, $a \approx -0.744$, $b\approx0.668$. As $n\to\infty$, $a \to 1$ and $b \to 0$.